# Arbitrage argument with bonds

Tags: bond, arbitrage

Let $B(t,T)$ denote the cost at time t of a risk-free 1 euro bond, at time T. Assume that the interest rate is a deterministic function. Show that the absence of arbitrage requires that:

$ B(0,1) B(1,2) = B(0,2)$

For instance, could you give a detailed explanation of what to do if $B(0,1)B(1,2) > B(0,2)$ ?

Comment: What have you tried to solve this problem?

Comment: I have to suppose two cases:

$B(0,1)B(1,2) >B(0,2) $

and

$B(0,1)B(1,2) <B(0,2) $

and show that both lead to an arbitrage

Comment: As usual, to make a profit you sell the thing(s) which is most expensive and buy the thing(s) which is cheaper.

Comment: Yeah ok, but I don't understand in real life, what does it mean for example to sell $B(0,1)B(1,2) $ and buy $B(0,2)$

Comment: Try thinking of borrowing money instead of selling a bond and of lending money instead of buying a bond

Comment: How do you get positive payoff with probability 1 if $B(0,1)B(1,2) > B(0,2) $? I really don't understand

Comment: Think of "buying $B(t_1,t_2)$" as two cash flows: you put in cash at time $t_1$ and you get (receive) cash at time $t_2$. "selling $B(t_1,t_2)$" is the opposite: you receive cash first and you have to repay (return) cash at $t_2$